# block BufferedReader until data appears

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, bufferedreader

Im not sure If I have this description correct, but here goes with the explanation.

I have a client side message processing system, that looks much like this: *(it runs in a separate thread)*

```
public void run() {
    String line;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine( )) == null) { Thread.sleep(10); }; 

            if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith("PING ")) {
                // Autorespond to server pings
                server.Write("PONG " + line.substring(5));
            }
            else {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }

}
```

What I really, REALLY, want to do, is replace this line: `while ((line = reader.readLine( )) == null) { Thread.sleep(10); }` with something else, anything else, that isn't an essentially infinite loop.

**Code Breakdown**
Loop forever until line contains some data.  If its a ping request, auto respond and start over.  If its not, notify the observer with the message received, and then start over.

The observer model works, not worried about that.  The reader actually does work, as is...but it consumes a LOT of processor sitting there in an infinite loop, checking things.

**The Question**
How can I use some kind of concurrency, wait, or whatever model so that the thread itself will simply wait until the BufferedReader actually has data to read?  Is there even a way to do that, or is that `Thread.Sleep(10)` I added actually the best way to keep from eating all my processor ad infinitum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I really, REALLY, want to do, is replace this line: while ((line = reader.readLine( )) == null) { Thread.sleep(10); } with something else, anything else, that isn't an essentially infinite loop.

You have a basic misunderstanding here. `readLine()` *does* block until data appears. It only returns `null` when you have reached end of stream, i.e. end of file or the peer has closed the connection. You don't need the sleep; you just need to reverse the test to `!= null` and put the code that handles the data inside the loop.

At the moment you are spinning in your loop *at* end of stream, which will never terminate.

Comment: Thank you.  How I failed to pick up on that I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

if `reader` is associated to a socket/(unknown-length stream), so there is no end of line, so there is no null returning. you know the most important thing here is protocol, both client and server should know about the how data is sent and received, for example, in `HTTP` protocol header size is unknown, so both server and client expect an empty line(`\r\n`) witch indicates the end of the header.
so at the first you need to have your own protocol, second beware about the null value.

```
public void run() {
    String line;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true) {
            line = reader.readLine( );//it throws exception if client/server closes the stream.
            if(line==null){return;/*break;*/}
            if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith("PING ")) {
                // Autorespond to server pings
                server.Write("PONG " + line.substring(5));
            }
            else {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //do something here
        }
      }
    }

}
```

also there is no need for `Thread.sleep()`, because I/O operations blocks until some data is available, even for 2 yearz.

Comment: This is all nonsense. readLine() *returns null* if the peer has closed the connection. Sockets have nothing to do with whether there is an end of line, and whether there is an end of line has nothing to do with retuning null. Your code doesn't check the result of readLine() for null, which alone indicates that it is completely untested guesswork.

Comment: I really wondered how does it get null when the stream size is unknown!?

Comment: So in other words you don't know how it behaves. You're just guessing. You're answering questions when you should be asking them. When the peer closes the connection, TCP sends a thing called a FIN, which ultimately causes readLine() to return null. If it doesn't know to return null, how would it know to throw an exception? ***Clearly*** you have never tried this, which basically disqualifies you from answering questions about it.

Comment: Hmm, good catch, so all is here checking the null after got String, thanks :) . I got some misunderstanding from `Socket` javadoc.

Comment: I don't see how. The Javadoc for Socket doesn't say anything about what BufferedReader.readLine() returns. Nor does it give any impression that it is non-blocking.

Comment: no buddy, I mean about the closing the stream and the socket. this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) and this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29) anyway thanks, I own you a coffee/beer :D, I really didn't know about the possible null response at the end of the session.

Comment: Well I think you misunderstood something all right, but I still don't see how you can plausibly blame it in the Javadoc.

Comment: I didn't blame, I said misunderstand, I updated the answer. thanks again :D.

Comment: This is wrong. Sockets do definitely have an end in which they return null.